# python37: Does @dataset call super.__init__(...)?

Tags: python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Suppose I have a complicated class with a lot of inputs.  This class is not a dataclass class. Further, if I import it explicitly, I would like it to complain if I do not provide all of the arguments.

However, for interfacing purposes and clean code, I would like to define default values for the constructors and pass around arguments for the complex class as, more or less, a 'defined' dict.

This is a good task for the dataclass, and I have defined a dataclass class containing all the arguments with defaults, and which I modify and manipulate.

```
@dataclass
ComplicatedClassArgs:
   arg1: int
   arg2: bool = False
   ...
```

My question amounts to: can I write the following, and expect and/or tell the dataclass to call super.**init**(...) with all the named attributes I have defined?

```
@dataclass
ComplicatedClassArgs(ComplicatedClass):
    arg1: int
    arg2: bool = False

    def some_meta_arg_manipulation_function(...):
        pass

    def some_other_arg_related_function(...):
        pass
```

Such that I know I have composed a more advanced inner class behavior with a dataclass entry point?

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your use case, but it looks to me like inheritance is the wrong tool for the job here. How about a simple `@classmethod`?

```py
@dataclass
ComplicatedClassArgs:
    arg1: int
    arg2: bool

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, kwargs=None):
        """"ComplicatedClassArgs factory.

        This method provides sensible default values that 
        may or may not be replaced through the input kwargs. 
        """
        if kwargs is None:
            kwargs = {}
        default_params = {
            'arg1': 1,
            'arg2': False
        }
        return cls(**{**default_params, **kwargs})

>>> ComplicatedClassArgs()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: __init__() missing .. required positional arguments
>>> ComplicatedClassArgs.from_dict()
ComplicatedClassArgs(arg1=1, arg2=False)
```

Comment: yeah, so I have many of these things, and the objective of inheritance, from my viewpoint, is code compression.  I have repetitive code, and would like to inherit the repetitive code in my dataclasses, that's all

Comment: Maybe you can include a list of requirements in your post. What I understood right now is that 1) you have a bunch of dataclasses 2) you want to force direct calls to `__init__` to provide all attributes 3) you want an separate call that allows for some default values 4) you want to share this pattern with as little boilerplate as possible. Is that correct?